# iTunes 10 sharing not working

Tags: windows-7, itunes, iphone, bonjour, home-sharing

I have two PCs running Windows 7 64-bit. I also have an iPhone 4. Both computers are wired into the same router, a Netgear WNDR3700, and are on the same network. The iPhone is wireless and also on the same network. Both windows machines are in the same homegroup. These devices can all easily communicate with each other over the network without issue. Every single network application, even Windows file sharing, is communicating between these devices except for iTunes.

Both PCs are running the newest 64-bit iTunes 10.5.3.3. I tried restarting iTunes, restarting the bonjour service, and restarting the computers completely. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling iTunes and bonjour on both machines. I tried disabling home sharing and enabling home sharing. I tried enabling and disabling windows firewall. I tried to use the iPhone remote app. Nothing works. The sharing icons never appear in the sidebar of either iTunes. The sharing icon never appears in the music app on the iPhone.

A few weeks ago, I think before some iTunes updates, it was working a little bit. If I restarted both iTunes they would detect, and I could stream for awhile. After a period of time it would just stop working and I could restart both iTunes to make it work again. Now it's just not working at all under any circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

Be patient. iTunes is extremely slow on Windows, and 64 bit windows version is still a bit beta. I have a very similar set up and it shares the libraries between 3 PCs (win 7 64bit). As I have a very large library, iTunes can take several minutes to load it up on the older PC, and that's not a function of the speed of the network.

1. Check (Edit, Preferences, Sharing) that the library is shared inside preferences. The Home Sharing check box is optional.
2. Check that each version of iTunes on each computer is authorized to the same apple account. I'm not sure if this is absolutely necessary but that could be why you are having trouble (I have one account and so does my hubby, but our itunes has both accounts registered).
3. Check that the "other" PC can "see" your main iTunes library outside of iTunes – network security, file sharing may not permit
   the other pc access to the iTunes folder.  I don't use "home group" windows sharing and iTunes can't share folders that windows locks down.

As to the iPhone, I use an app to "see" the iTunes library.  Otherwise the phone only plays what was sync'd to it. The remote app works just fine on the PC that is playing the file. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for several days.  After updating the Apple TV and iTunes, connection to my PC was not working.  AirPlay was OK, however connecting the Apple TV or the iPhone 4S remote app to my PC was not possible.  The connection shut down after few minutes, songs could not be loaded and the devices couldn't see the iTunes library.

The solution that worked for me: Uninstall Bonjour and iTunes, restart Windows and reinstall itunes.